# mysql is using key (primary) not listed in possible_keys

Tags: mysql

my table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE `payments`  (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `actionType` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `payDate` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `isCoupayOrder` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `index`(`payDate`, `actionType`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 6543773 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

when i execute this query command,

```
explain select * from payments where actionType in ('APPROVED','CANCEL') and deleted <> 1 and isCoupayOrder = 0 and (payDate between '2020-05-01' and '2020-11-01') order by id asc limit 20;
```

the result is this:

```
id 1
select_type SIMPLE
table payments
type index 
possible_keys index
key PRIMARY 
key_len 8
extra Using where
```

i don't understand why the key is primary, means scan the whole table? it's not even listed in possible_keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer chooses not to use the index `index` for the where query. This could be caused by the fact the optimizer thinks it is faster to do a table scan as you select all the columns (`select *`), some of them not found in the index.

When it's doing the table scan, it can use the PRIMARY index to satisfy the `ORDER BY`-clause. Hence the use of it.

Comment: i tested "order by payDate", now the key changed to "index".